# Pull requests in Android Studio: Can't load data from GitHub. [Could not resolve to a Repository with the name xxx]

Tags: git, android-studio, github, pull-request

I am having this issue in Android Studio while trying to open Pull requests in the IDE. I have two accounts logged in for github in my Android studio (personal and work)

> Can't load data from GitHub. [Could not resolve to a Repository with the name xxx]

I looked up online for some solutions and so far I've tried -

1. Removing my account and adding it again using token.
2. IDE invalidate cache and restart

None of the solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried solving this for an hour and found nothing online but eventually it worked so sharing what worked for me here:

I found this dialog that opens when:

```
(Pull request -> Settings icon at top right -> click on Change Repository or Account
```

and then I clicked on the account I needed to access that specific repository. In my case, the issue was I had two accounts logged in (Personal and work) and even though it's strange because I remember opening pull requests a week back and then it was working. But today it gave an error. But anyway, this fixed it. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have this option at the top of the settings icon, but going to the Android Studio GitHub settings removing and adding my account with a token solved the problem.